# Vue.js componente con inputs

Tags: vue.js

Estoy creando un componente con vue.js que contiene varios inputs. Quiero crear un botón que al ser presionado me agregue un nuevo componente (sin refrescar los anteriores componentes que tengo creados en el DOM). Cómo podría hacerlo, tengo el siguiente código del componente

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
    Vue.component('todo-item', {

                template: `

         <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" title="Remover item">X</a></div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" v-model="pre"></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" v-model="can"></textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price">{{ pre*can }}</span></td>
      </tr>

        `
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con:

```js
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    template: `
       <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea></textarea><a class="delete" title="Remover item">X</a></div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost" v-model="pre"></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty" v-model="can"></textarea></td>
          <td><span class="price">{{ pre*can }}</span></td>
        </tr>
    `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    components: 0      
  },
  methods: {
   addComponent() {
     this.components++
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addComponent">
    add component
  </button>
  <todo-item v-for="(component, index) in components" :key="index"/>
</div>
```